# create payment with the token of a saved card and 3d secure

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe for payments.
I managed to save a card by obtaining the token, created the customer, and associated the token with the customer.
Now I am trying to make a backend (node) side payments using this code:

```
    const createCharge = await stripe.charges.create({
        amount,
        currency: 'eur',
        customer: user.stripeCustomerId,
        card: cardId,
        description: `userId: ${user._id}`,
      });
```

If the card does not require authentication it works perfectly while if authentication is required it obviously fails with the error: `authentication_required`.
I tried to add authentication with 3d secure in-app but without success, this is what I tried but I always get errors and no authentication is done

```
    const { paymentIntent, error } = await confirmPayment(clientSecret.client_secret, {
            payment_method_options:{
                "card": {
                    "installments": null,
                    "network": null,
                    "request_three_d_secure": "any"
                }
            },
            type: 'Card',
            cardDetails: this.props.cardList[0].cardId,
            payment_method:'creditCard',
            setupFutureUsage: 'OffSession',
        });
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: Yep you have to use PaymentIntents, not the stripe.charges API. So you should follow https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment. You don't mention exactly what kind of error you get so it's hard to help!

Comment: I followed this guide but it shows how to pay by inserting a card (presentPaymentSheet).
I would need to authenticate and pay using the token of the previously saved card...

Comment: Do you actually have an existing Stripe account with saved cards? Because there's no reason to use tokens(the way you created a token+saved to a customer was probably the legacy way(https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards#saving-credit-card-details-for-later)  but you probably built it recently for some reason?)

I would start by getting that first guide fully working end-to-end so you have a working one-off payment flow, then you can expand it by adding parts from https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment so that it also saves the cards!

Comment: I will do as you advise me!
Thanks!
I was totally on the wrong way